# Django Celery create only one task, not periodic

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I am testing django_celery and could not be happier. Really easy to set up and does a lot of stuff I want.

I have some tasks that I want to run just when the user wants, not periodically. To do this I created some [django actions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) so when the user selects items in an app and selects the action I fire up some tasks. This is working fine but I also would like to have an admin page when the user can create new tasks (by demand, no scheduling) from the existing tasks on tasks.py

Is there an existing solution for these problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I learnt most of what I know from here -> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_x8jqP-ZSE&list=PLxxA5z-8B2xk4szCgFmgonNcCboyNneMD&index=30 Perhaps it can help you out.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You have to write your custom admin solutions.

Comment: That is an amazing resource Games. Unfortunately doesn't solve my problem. Is not that a bad thing to create a custom action for each task, and it actually makes sense if you are using database Objects on the task. But I still wonder why the tasks table in the djcelery app doesn't have a create task option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own admin or extend the current one to support what you want.

Give your tests names and create a model that stores the name and the arguments to use. Then you can have a link/button that runs the task on demand.

Or, you could use a Django Form to enter custom arguments each time rather than storing them in a database model.

Comment: I created some django admin actions and I am calling the tasks that way. It appears that those are the possible solutions. Just was double checking that nothing existed already. Thanks.